# Geospatial queries polygons (doctrine2)

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, geospatial, polygons

I would like to know if there is a way to execute polygons queries in PHP with doctrine2 and mongodb.
(As seen in the doc : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-BoundsQueries)

I know that the near, withinCenter and withinBox are possibles are implemented in Doctrine2 and work fine, but what about polygons ?
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/geospatial-queries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does now :)

```
$queryBuilder
    ->field('loc')
    ->withinPolygon(array(0, 0), array(2, 0), array(0, 2));
```

See [60a99e5](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/commit/60a99e5ce36aa34a5ae9f5fe9623e84bfddc99c4) and the corresponding unit test. An exception will be thrown if less than three points are provided, since that cannot express a polygon.